# VSCode - Remote SSH - Git Pull/Sync Not working - It hangs without errors - SSH Key has no passphrase

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

VSCODE SSH Extension GIT Pull/Sync doesn't work, it hangs.

```
1.Install SSH-Extension

2. Connect to SSH Host -

3. Open existing git Repo from remote server which is cloned from our internal git server with ssh URL using RSA Key pair without passphrase

4. run git sync from git menu or git pull from a terminal. This doesn't finish
```

- I am trying to setup remote SSH development on windows 2010 laptop.
- I am able to access our internal git server using ssh both from dev server and laptop using keypair.
- I am admin on both laptop and server and made sure ssh and local git are working properly, bu cloning repo using SSH on both laptop and server from our git server and successfully running git pull and git push from both laptop and server individually.
- On both machines, I am using the same identity, the same user accounts. On the git server profile I have only one public key and a private key is replicated on both .ssh folders of my laptop and servers username/.ssh folder, private key doesn't have a passphrase.

From Remote Desktop In Dev server

Powershell

```
    cd Repo
    git pull
    works fine
```

Git Bash

```
    Cd repo
    git pull
    works fine
```

from local computer PowerShell ->

```
    ssh user@remotehost
    cd repo
    git pull --> this works fine no issues
```

```
    EXTHOST.LOG 
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.021] [exthost] [info] extension host started
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.293] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.debug-auto-launch {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.debug-auto-launch","_lower":"vscode.debug-auto-launch"},"activationEvent":"*"}
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.294] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///c:/Users/<REMOVED>/.vscode-server/bin/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/extensions/debug-auto-launch/dist/extension
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.301] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.emmet {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.emmet","_lower":"vscode.emmet"},"activationEvent":"*"}
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.301] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///c:/Users/<REMOVED>/.vscode-server/bin/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/extensions/emmet/dist/extension
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.334] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.git {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.git","_lower":"vscode.git"},"activationEvent":"*"}
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.334] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///c:/Users/<REMOVED>/.vscode-server/bin/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/extensions/git/dist/main
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.397] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.github-authentication {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.github-authentication","_lower":"vscode.github-authentication"},"activationEvent":"*"}
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.397] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///c:/Users/<REMOVED>/.vscode-server/bin/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/extensions/github-authentication/dist/extension.js
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.402] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.merge-conflict {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.merge-conflict","_lower":"vscode.merge-conflict"},"activationEvent":"*"}
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.402] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///c:/Users/<REMOVED>/.vscode-server/bin/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/extensions/merge-conflict/dist/extension
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.408] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.search-result {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.search-result","_lower":"vscode.search-result"},"activationEvent":"*"}
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.408] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///c:/Users/<REMOVED>/.vscode-server/bin/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/extensions/search-result/dist/extension.js
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.410] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.vscode-account {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.vscode-account","_lower":"vscode.vscode-account"},"activationEvent":"*"}
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.410] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///c:/Users/<REMOVED>/.vscode-server/bin/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/extensions/vscode-account/dist/extension.js
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.464] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#_doActivateExtension vscode.npm {"startup":true,"extensionId":{"value":"vscode.npm","_lower":"vscode.npm"},"activationEvent":"workspaceContains:package.json"}
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.464] [exthost] [info] ExtensionService#loadCommonJSModule file:///c:/Users/<REMOVED>/.vscode-server/bin/0ba0ca52957102ca3527cf479571617f0de6ed50/extensions/npm/dist/main
    [2020-04-03 21:20:36.601] [exthost] [info] eager extensions activated
```

```
    GIT.LOG
    Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
    Using git 2.26.0.windows.1 from C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe


> git rev-parse --show-toplevel
    > git rev-parse --git-dir
    Open repository: e:\REPO
    > git status -z -u
    > git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
    > git rev-parse master
    > git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name master@{u}
    > git rev-list --left-right master...refs/remotes/origin/master
    > git for-each-ref --format %(refname) %(objectname) --sort -committerdate
    > git remote --verbose
    > git config --get commit.template
    > git check-ignore -v -z --stdin
    > git fetch
```

```
    Both Git-hub Authentication.log and Account.log are empty files.
```

We (I and our git admin) also performed debug with our local git server Splunk log. When I am running git pull or git sync from VSCODE using the above steps I don't see any requests reaching to git servers.

I have also tried with different sets of public and private key pairs on server and laptop (also added both public keys on git server profile) still got the same results.

Am I missing anything??

Comment: It's really hard to tell that you even have a problem here. All the text indicates everything is working. Is there a question? An environment that doesn't work?

Comment: I realize it was not super clear, sorry I was all over place. I tried to clarify it little bit more in the beginning in the question. In nutshell git pull/push works on remote machine when I’m connected through Powershell Ssh but doesn’t work through VSCODE SSH.

Comment: it still hangs in both windows and linux (tried on Windows 10 and Ubuntu in WSL). To replicate create an SSH key with ed25519 algo and try git push, git pull from VSC UI, it will hang but if you do it in command line it works, I think the prompt that you get to enter the paraphrase produces the hang

Comment: As @downvoteit mentioned. I encountered this issue today as well and I had to push via terminal . If your SSH key has a password and you try to push via vscode (on Windows 11 w/ Ubuntu in WSL)  it does not work.