# Git Pull/Push not working on VS Code server

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have a Desktop computer and a laptop.
I have setup VS Code on the desktop and synced some repoes (ssh clone) and it works perfectly.
On my Laptop, I ssh with same account to VS Code and opens the cloned folders, but from there I can't pull/push the repo's.

I had this running before I had to reinstall my desktop, but I can't figure out what should be different, or what/where any relevant logfiles is.

Both desktop and laptop are running Windows 11, one change though is that the Deskop is running preview build of Windows 11.

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94417, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61022777/11107541. also https://stackoverflow.com/q/71141375/11107541. do you get any error messages anywhere? (check also the Output Panel's various channels)